# Best way to keep my .net site alive at the host?

Tags: .net, hosting

I have a .net website that does not get many visitors and this means that when it does, it will have to start the site and this takes some time.

What is the best way to keep the site alive and ready? I have found a couple of ping services on the Internet, but I'm not sure if this is the way to go. But if it is, which one should I use?

The host service does hold a lot of other customer's web-applications.

Comment: [Check this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39118/Keep-Your-Website-Alive-Don-t-Let-IIS-Recycle-Your)

I reckon this should still work

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to IIS configuration then you may do the following.

In IIS7.

- Go to "Application Pools" item found right under your server name in IIS tree.
- Then right click the pool containing your application and go to "Advanced Settings"
- In advanced settings under Process Model find "Idle Time-out (minutes)" setting.
- Set it to a very high value and that will keep your app runnning.

In IIS6.

- Go to "Application Pools" item found right under your server name in IIS tree.
- Then right click the pool containing your application and open properties
- In the properties dialog go to Performance tab and increase idle timeout - very first setting on that tab.

Changing setting for the application pool will change it for all apps running in that pool so be careful with it. You may want to create a separate pool for your web app.

Comment: Thanks but I do not got access to the IIS and also I do think that you could set those settings you sugest to 0 and thay will be infinity.

Answer (score 1):

For workaround, I always use schedule job/command script to open browser and access the site in given cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but setting the `Idle Time-out` will only cause the application pool worker process to stay alive. When you have a recycle policy (and I think you need one) it will kill the process anyway. The only solution for =< .net 4 is to call a page. Calling a page does not mean your application is competely loaded. Each page can have it's own assembly for instance.

.net 4.5 and greater in combination with IIS 7.5 or greater has build in features to do this: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

Answer (score -1):

It depends no what version of .Net and IIS you are using but with 4.0 and IIS 7 you can add a web config key to instruct IIS to keep the site when there's infrequent requests.

Add these to your web.config;

```
<add key="UseAppKeepAlive" value="false" />
<add key="AppKeepAliveUrl" value="" />
```

If using IIS 7 with Integrated Pipeline mode then you must specify the url to the root of your site in AppKeepAliveUrl like http://yourdomain.com/Default.aspx

See the following article for guidance;

http://www.mojoportal.com/using-the-appkeepalive-task-to-speed-up-a-low-traffic-site.aspx

Comment: This seem to be mojoportal specific and not ASP.NET?

Comment: Hi, What element does the keep alive setting go under? I've added it under <appSettings> seems to be working.